# How to fix "TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X'" error

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to fit the model using `LinearRegression`

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y)
mod = make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(degree=1), 
LinearRegression(normalize=True))
mod.fit(x=X_train, y=y_train)
```

and got an error message

```
fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X'
```

How can I fix it, please?

Comment: The parameters are capital X and capital Y.

Answer (score 1):

[Docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.fit) for `Pipeline.fit` says capital X, try:

```
mod.fit(X=X_train, y=y_train)
```